# Is a non-const rvalue reference possible in C++03?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

Is it possible to bind an object returned from a function to a non-const reference of a purely virtual supertype of that type before C++11?

For example, suppose I had this code:

```
class IFoo
{
public:

    virtual void bar() =0;

};

class Foo : public IFoo
{
public:

    virtual void bar()
    { cout << "Hello, World!" << endl; };

};
```

In C++11 I could do this:

```
IFoo && f = Foo();
f.bar();
```

I know, that I could use the following before C++11:

```
const IFoo & f = Foo();
```

But then I'm not allowed to call any non-const method on `f`. Is there a way to get around this in C++03?

Comment: short answer: no, you cannot bind a rvalue to a non-const lvalue reference (VC may allow you to do this, but is not standard compliant)

Comment: What would be the use ?

Comment: @Quentin: Just like in the example, I would like to return references to objects from functions and store them polymorphically - without passing pointers around.

Comment: You can rely on implicit conversions when they are needed - why bother throwing away type information beforehand ?

Comment: @Quentin: Because that function actually is a method of just that purely virtual class. So, in the example above, IFoo would have a function returning an instance of IFoo. I don't know the concrete type, which the sub-class wants to return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a const-cast:

```
const IFoo & f0 = Foo();
IFoo & f = const_cast<IFoo &>(f0);
f.bar();
```

Comment: smart way of doing it! +1

Comment: The first version seems to work, but when using the function, my program crashes saying: `pure virtual method called;
terminate called without an active exception`

Comment: @Callidior: Of course, I'm sorry. The wrapping in a function destroys the lifetime extension, a very silly mistake on my part. Removed.

Comment: Is this solution safe to use? May the obtained non-const rvalue reference even be stored in a member variable without being freed at some uncontrollable point of time?

Comment: @Callidior: The object lives for as long as the original reference variable, and no longer. Don't go around storing references to it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
Foo f_;
IFoo& f=f_;
```

This solves your sample problem.  It may not solve your real problem.

Comment: You're right... unfortunately, my real problem is more complex, since I want to return the rvalue reference from a function.